# Работа с классом в PHP

Tags: php, классы

Есть вот такой вот класс

```
class defaultArray {
  public $def = ''; 
  public $trim_charlist = '\xA0 \x00..\x1F'; 
  private $data = array();
  private $str;

#--------------------------------------
  public function __construct($array = false){
    if($array){ $this->data = $array; }
  }

  public function __toString(){
    return $this->str;
  }

#--------------------------------------
  public function arr(){
    return $this->data;
  }

  public function get($name){
    $this->str = isset($this->data[$name]) ? $this->data[$name] : $this->def;
    return $this;
  }

  public function set($name, $val){
    $this->data[$name] = $val;
    return $this;
  }

  public function del($name){
    unset($this->data[$name]);
    return $this;
  }

  public function add($add){
    if(is_array($add)){
      $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $add); 
    }else{ $this->data[] = $add; }
    return $this;
  }

#--------------------------------------
  public function trim(){
    $this->str = trim($this->str, $this->trim_charlist);
    return $this;
  }

  public function replace($what, $to){
    $this->str = str_replace($what, $to, $this->str);
    return $this;
  }

  public function iconv($from, $to){
    $this->str = iconv($from, $to, $this->str);
    return $this;
  }

  public function str_replace($from, $to){
    $this->str = str_replace($from, $to, $this->str);
    return $this;
  }

  public function preg_replace($from, $to){
    $this->str = preg_replace($from, $to, $this->str);
    return $this;
  }

#-------

  public function preg_match($reg){
    return preg_match($reg, $this->str);
  }

}
```

При выполнении кода

```
$_post = new defaultArray($_POST);
$name = $_post->get('name')->trim(); 
$place = $_post->get('place')->trim(); 
echo $name;
```

Выводится значение из ячейки массива, к которой в последний раз обращались, т.е. 'place', как это можно исправить?

Comment: в таком виде - никак, вы должны какой-то новый объект, имеющий метод trim() и пр. ,  возвращать когда делаете get(), а вы возвращаете тот-же самый. Короче говоря - тут два разных класса в один зачем-то сложены, так работать не будет. Быстрый фикс - возвращать строку а не объект в методе trim() или клонировать $(this) и возвращать его.

Comment: На счет клонирования $(this), можно пример?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php